# Extract Universal Dependencies using Stanford Parser in Python

Tags: python, nlp, dependencies, nltk, stanford-nlp

I want to extract relative clauses from sentences and want to use Stanford Parser in NLTK (in python). I thought about using information about dependencies within the sentences in order to detect relative clauses. This is the code I have so far:

```py
STANFORD = os.path.abspath("stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05")
# Create the server
server = CoreNLPServer(
   os.path.join(STANFORD, "stanford-corenlp-3.9.2.jar"),
   os.path.join(STANFORD, "stanford-corenlp-3.9.2-models.jar"),    
)
sentence = "The play, which started last week, has been sold out ever since."
parser = CoreNLPDependencyParser()
parse = next(parser.raw_parse(sentence))
print(parse)
```

and my output looks like this:

```
{0: {'address': 0,
                 'ctag': 'TOP',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ROOT': [11]}),
                 'feats': None,
                 'head': None,
                 'lemma': None,
                 'rel': None,
                 'tag': 'TOP',
                 'word': None},
             1: {'address': 1,
                 'ctag': 'DT',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                 'feats': '_',
                 'head': 2,
                 'lemma': 'the',
                 'rel': 'det',
                 'tag': 'DT',
                 'word': 'The'},
             2: {'address': 2,
                 'ctag': 'NN',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
                                     {'acl:relcl': [5],
                                      'det': [1],
                                      'punct': [3, 8]}),
                 'feats': '_',
                 'head': 11,
                 'lemma': 'play',
                 'rel': 'nsubjpass',
                 'tag': 'NN',
                 'word': 'play'},
             3: {'address': 3,
                 'ctag': ',',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                 'feats': '_',
                 'head': 2,
                 'lemma': ',',
                 'rel': 'punct',
                 'tag': ',',
                 'word': ','},
             4: {'address': 4,
                 'ctag': 'WDT',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                 'feats': '_',
                 'head': 5,
                 'lemma': 'which',
                 'rel': 'nsubj',
                 'tag': 'WDT',
                 'word': 'which'},
             5: {'address': 5,
                 'ctag': 'VBD',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
                                     {'nmod:tmod': [7],
                                      'nsubj': [4]}),
                 'feats': '_',
                 'head': 2,
                 'lemma': 'start',
                 'rel': 'acl:relcl',
                 'tag': 'VBD',
                 'word': 'started'},
             6: {'address': 6,
                 'ctag': 'JJ',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                 'feats': '_',
                 'head': 7,
                 'lemma': 'last',
                 'rel': 'amod',
                 'tag': 'JJ',
                 'word': 'last'},
             7: {'address': 7,
                 'ctag': 'NN',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'amod': [6]}),
                 'feats': '_',
                 'head': 5,
                 'lemma': 'week',
                 'rel': 'nmod:tmod',
                 'tag': 'NN',
                 'word': 'week'},
             8: {'address': 8,
                 'ctag': ',',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                 'feats': '_',
                 'head': 2,
                 'lemma': ',',
                 'rel': 'punct',
                 'tag': ',',
                 'word': ','},
             9: {'address': 9,
                 'ctag': 'VBZ',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                 'feats': '_',
                 'head': 11,
                 'lemma': 'have',
                 'rel': 'aux',
                 'tag': 'VBZ',
                 'word': 'has'},
             10: {'address': 10,
                  'ctag': 'VBN',
                  'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                  'feats': '_',
                  'head': 11,
                  'lemma': 'be',
                  'rel': 'auxpass',
                  'tag': 'VBN',
                  'word': 'been'},
             11: {'address': 11,
                  'ctag': 'VBN',
                  'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
                                      {'advmod': [13, 14],
                                       'aux': [9],
                                       'auxpass': [10],
                                       'compound:prt': [12],
                                       'nsubjpass': [2],
                                       'punct': [15]}),
                  'feats': '_',
                  'head': 0,
                  'lemma': 'sell',
                  'rel': 'ROOT',
                  'tag': 'VBN',
                  'word': 'sold'},
             12: {'address': 12,
                  'ctag': 'RP',
                  'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                  'feats': '_',
                  'head': 11,
                  'lemma': 'out',
                  'rel': 'compound:prt',
                  'tag': 'RP',
                  'word': 'out'},
             13: {'address': 13,
                  'ctag': 'RB',
                  'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                  'feats': '_',
                  'head': 11,
                  'lemma': 'ever',
                  'rel': 'advmod',
                  'tag': 'RB',
                  'word': 'ever'},
             14: {'address': 14,
                  'ctag': 'IN',
                  'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                  'feats': '_',
                  'head': 11,
                  'lemma': 'since',
                  'rel': 'advmod',
                  'tag': 'IN',
                  'word': 'since'},
             15: {'address': 15,
                  'ctag': '.',
                  'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                  'feats': '_',
                  'head': 11,
                  'lemma': '.',
                  'rel': 'punct',
                  'tag': '.',
                  'word': '.'}})
```

However, I would like to have an output like described here https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf, but I just don't understand which parser/functions I have to use... Maybe I'm just overseeing it, I don't know.

In the document, this is stated:

*ref : referent*.
A referent of the head of an NP is the relative word introducing the relative clause modifying the NP.
“I saw the book which you bought”   ref(book, which) (p.10)

So I would like to have an output like

```
ref(book, which)
```

if that's possible.

Comment: The pdf you referenced is 28 pages long. Can you be more specific with the desired output?

Comment: Oh, good point!
So it the document it says it's possible to get ouput like this:

ref (book, which) (p.10)

So basically a tuple of two words and the dependency

Comment: As far as I understand the docs, you will have to iterate over the tree structure and extract this relation manually according to the pointers of "head" and "rel", which points  from the NP to the head verb of the relative clause.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I know which part of the sentence is the relative clause, or the head of the relative clause?

Comment: That is in the docs, if I remember correctly. In the output, you get indices like in 1, you see as value for key "head" index 2, which points at the values of key 2, which is NN, the noun, giving you "the play". In the same way, you can determine the relation to the relative clause. If you post the full output, we can have a look together.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help! I added the full output. 
So if we look at "which", which is the "start" of the relative clause, it has as key value for "head" index 5,which points at "started". "Started" on the other hand has as key value for "head" index 2, which points at "play"?

Comment: You start from index 0, which is TOP,. From there, you can get to the matrix verb "sell" accroding to "root" in default dict for the dependencies, in index 11. From there, you get via "deps:nsubjpass" to index 2, which is your subject. in "deps:relcl" you find index 5, which points at the verb of the relative clause, from which your get via "deps:nsubj" to which. You can also take the reverse way, but it is better to start at root for explanation.

Comment: oh wow thanks that makes sense! Thanks that you took the time to explain it to me :) Do you have a hint what the implementation to automatically find the rc could look like...?

Comment: nvw, I use another parser. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract relative clauses, I use another parser, namely `CoreNLPParser()` which gives me a nltk tree. From there, I just need to extract the correct label, join the leaves and voilà, I have the relative clause.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59430805/5) to the question [Extract Universal Dependencies using Stanford Parser in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430805/extract-universal-dependencies-using-stanford-parser-in-python) by the OP [maeven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12572713/maeven) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>